# MVC3 Null value when I click next page on my WebGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I click the next page in my webGrid I get a null value passed into my Action method and I don't understand why.  When I do the original POST the value is there.

Here is my controler page:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {                     
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Results()
    {
        string year = Request.Form["testCriteria.Year"];

        List<TestCriteriaResults> test = new List<TestCriteriaResults>();

        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "one", Value3="three", Value4="Four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3="three", Value4="four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });           

        TestCriteriaConsolidated combined = new TestCriteriaConsolidated();
        combined.testCriteriaResults = test;

        return PartialView(combined);
    }
```

Here is the partial view where I'm trying to get the 'Year' when the paging is clicked

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestCriteriaConsolidated


@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home"))
{
 <div style="float:left">
                <div style="font-weight:bold">                
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.testCriteria.Year)
                </div>
                <div style="width:110px; ">   
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.testCriteria.Year, new SelectList(new[] 
                     { 

                        new SelectListItem{ Text="All Years", Value=" " },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2010", Value="2010" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2009", Value="2009" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2008", Value="2008" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2007", Value="2007" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2006", Value="2006" }

                     }, "Value", "Text", "1"), new { @style = "width: 100px; margin-top: 5px" })          
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="float:left">
                <div>                
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div style="width:100px; ">                                
                     <input type="submit"  value="Results" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

}

Here is my WebGrid code:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestCriteriaConsolidated


       @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@if(Model.testCriteriaResults.Count() > 0)
{


var grid = new WebGrid(Model.testCriteriaResults,canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 2);
@grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.Numeric);     


    <div id="grid">
        @grid.GetHtml()

    </div>

 }
```

Comment: I should clarify...When I click the Submit button I get a Year value in the Results action method.  Then, when I click the next page from the webGrid it once again enters the Results action method but this time the Year value is null.